# Is it possible to access Secure Data Connector directly from Apps Script

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps-script, google-apps

Is it or will it be possible to access the Secure Data Connector protocol directly from Apps Script and not have to first draw into a Google Spreadsheet or piggy back on an App Engine app set-up just for the transfer of private data?

I'd like to use Apps Script to help drive a 'dashboard' of sorts to our private servers.

I have successfully connected to SDC using the spreadsheet method and given that works i'm sure i could set up an App Engine app to do the same. It would be better if there was a single SDC service available to Apps Script.

'#google-secure-data-connector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using an Apps Script to access data found in your company's intranet, there is a flag you can use: `{useIntranet:true}`

```
<? var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url , {useIntranet:true}); ?>
```

This is an example using UrlFetchApp, and the flag is fairly straightforward. I'm not sure what your use case is, but this will allow you to access data hosted on your network.